# Get keys of two dictionaries with matching values

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to compare two dictionaries by looking for equivalent keys, or rather the keys that have the same values, using python. There are two things I'm trying to do/find:

1. The keys from both dictionaries with the same values, and
2. The keys that don't have an equivalent key in the other dictionary.

My Dictionaries look something like this:

```
dict_1={
'3471': ['AY219713', 'AJ504663'], '3460': ['AJ621556', 'AJ575744'], '0': ['AM158981', 'AM158980', 'AM158982', 'AM158979', 'AY594216', 'AY594215', 'EU053207', 'AM392286', 'L26168', 'L37584']}

dict_2 = {'478': ['AY219713', 'AJ504663'], '43': ['AJ575744', 'AJ621556'], '2321': ['AM158979', 'L37584', 'AM158982', 'EU053207', 'AY594215', 'AM392286', 'AY594216', 'L26168', 'AM158981', 'AM158980', 'CP000758', 'AY776289', 'AJ242581', 'AM422370', 'U70978', 'AY457038', 'FR668302', 'AM422371', 'AM490632', 'AM490617', 'AJ242584']}
```

So I want to try and get output that looks something like this,

```
Matching keys from Dictionary 1 and Dictionary 2:
3471 = 478, 2 values in common
3460 = 43, 2 values in common

Keys with no equal match:
Dictionary 1 = 0, etc.
Dictionary 2 = 2321, etc.
```

Common keys with different values don't matter.

Comment: Do you care about common keys with different values? `'123': [1]; vs '123: [2];` for instance? Your example is ambiguous in that regard.

Comment: @aj8uppal I think that the formatting of the question was better before you changed it - it was easier to see what the keys were.

Comment: Thanks for asking, but no (I'll edit the post to acknowledge that point)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slight variation on aj8uppal's answer - this is a little cleaner about what it calls as a match and non-match, and I think the result is closer to what you were asking for. Admit it was in part inspired by aj8uppal; note I shortened `dict_1` and `dict_2` for readability, and I only sort them once (important when you have 5000 keys...):

```
dict_1 = {
'3471': ['AY219713', 'AJ504663'],
'3460': ['AJ621556', 'AJ575744'],
'0': ['AM158981', 'AM158980', 'AM158982']}

dict_2 = {
'478': ['AY219713', 'AJ504663'],
'43': ['AJ575744', 'AJ621556'],
'2321': ['AM158979', 'L37584', 'AM158982']}

match1 = {}
match2 = {}
# sort once: makes a difference when you have lots of elements
for k in dict_1:
  dict_1[k] = sorted(dict_1[k])
for j in dict_2:
  dict_2[j] = sorted(dict_2[j])
for k in dict_1:
  for j in dict_2:
    if (dict_1[k] == dict_2[j]):
      match1[k]=1
      match2[j]=1
      break;

print "matching keys:"
print list(match1)
print list(match2)
print "\nnon matching keys:"
print list(set(dict_1.keys()) - set(match1))
print list(set(dict_2.keys()) - set(match2))
```

This gives the following output:

```
matching keys:
['3471', '3460']
['478', '43']

non matching keys:
['0']
['2321']
```

Comment: +1 for using set difference on the last two lines. You can actually build a set of a dictionary's keys by just saying `set(dict_1)` (dictionaries iterate over their keys by default).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
dict_1={
'3471': ['AY219713', 'AJ504663'], '3460': ['AJ621556', 'AJ575744'], '0': ['AM158981', 'AM158980', 'AM158982', 'AM158979', 'AY594216', 'AY594215', 'EU053207', 'AM392286', 'L26168', 'L37584']}

dict_2 = {'478': ['AY219713', 'AJ504663'], '43': ['AJ575744', 'AJ621556'], '2321': ['AM158979', 'L37584', 'AM158982', 'EU053207', 'AY594215', 'AM392286', 'AY594216', 'L26168', 'AM158981', 'AM158980', 'CP000758', 'AY776289', 'AJ242581', 'AM422370', 'U70978', 'AY457038', 'FR668302', 'AM42237
for k in dict_1:
    for i in dict_2:
        if sorted(dict_1[k]) == sorted(dict_2[i]):
            matches.append((k, i))

for k in matches:
    print '%s = %s' %(k[0], k[1])
```

This runs as:

```
bash-3.2$ python sortkey.py
3471 = 478
3460 = 43
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it doesn't seem to be working for me! Also, I have many keys in both dictionaries, about 5000 in each, so I wouldn't want it to list how many keys it doesn't match.

Comment: Haha, it just started working but I had to stop it because it was listing thousands of lines per key!

Comment: Just remove the last `for` loop :)

Answer (score 1):

A bit of silly list comprehension using `sets` instead of `sorted list`

```
for x in [i[0] for i in filter(None,[["%s = %s" %(key1,key2) for key1 in dict_1.keys() if set(dict_1[key1]) == set(dict_2[key2])] for key2 in dict_2.keys()])]:
    print x
```

Comment: I suppose that `set` does a `sort`. Do you think the order of your solution is better than the two for's ?

Comment: @Floris I don't exactly know the performance of `set`.So, I can't answer your question. Ofcourse, it will be wiser to just sort 2 time if you have a very long list. I am just answering here as an alternative to `sorted` function.

Comment: A Python `set` is basically a dictionary with keys but no values. It doesn't `sort` but it does compute a hash value on each key. For a sequence of n items it should take O(n) time to build a set of those items.

Answer (score 1):

This works by inverting the dictionaries and going over a set of the keys (values for the original dictionaries).

```
dict_1 = {
'3471': ['AY219713', 'AJ504663'],
'3460': ['AJ621556', 'AJ575744'],
'0': ['AM158981', 'AM158980', 'AM158982']}

dict_2 = {
'478': ['AY219713', 'AJ504663'],
'43': ['AJ575744', 'AJ621556'],
'2321': ['AM158979', 'L37584', 'AM158982']}

def compare_dicts(D1, D2):
    dict_1 = {str(sorted(v)): k for k, v in D1.iteritems()}
    dict_2 = {str(sorted(v)): k for k, v in D2.iteritems()}
    KEYS  = set(dict_1.keys() + dict_2.keys())
    both = []
    just = {0:[], 1:[]}
    for k in KEYS:
        Vals = dict_1.get(k, False), dict_2.get(k, False)
        if all(map(bool, Vals)):
            both.append('{} = {}'.format(*map(str, Vals)))
        else:
            i = 0 if Vals[0] else 1
            just[i].append(Vals[i])

    print 'Matching keys from Dictionary 1 and Dictionary 2:'
    print '\n'.join(both)
    print
    print 'Keys with no equal match:'
    print 'Dictionary 1 = {}'.format(','.join(map(str, just[0])))
    print 'Dictionary 2 = {}'.format(','.join(map(str, just[1])))


compare_dicts(dict_1, dict_2)
```

This give the desired output of

```
Matching keys from Dictionary 1 and Dictionary 2:
3460 = 43
3471 = 478

Keys with no equal match:
Dictionary 1 = 0
Dictionary 2 = 2321
```